# What Haskell package has a unit functor/monad?

Tags: haskell, monads, functor

I'm looking for the unit functor/monad

```
data Unit a = Unit
```

I could easily recreate it, but I'd rather not duplicate something this basic. It used to live in `Control.Functor` in the category-extras package (http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/category-extras/0.1/doc/html/Control-Functor.html). I can't find it with Hoogle, or in the map of where the pieces of category-extras went to live (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/category-extras-1.0.2)

It seems like it should live in the transformers package, since that's where `Control.Monad.Identity` went (it's now `Data.Functor.Identity`).

The closest existing library code I can come up with is

```
type Unit a = Constant () a
```

using `Data.Functor.Constant` from the transformers package.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Proxy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagged-0.7/docs/Data-Proxy.html) type may be what you're after.

Comment: Excellent, that's exactly what I'm after; thank you very much. It didn't occur to me that `data Unit a = Unit` is the same thing I write for proxies, `data Proxy a = a`. It'd be awesome if Hoogle could search `data` declarations the same way it searches function signatures.